# NodeJS Application unable to access from Zuul API Gateway

Tags: node.js, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I created a Node.js (Using ExpressJS) [microservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDmAp.png) and registered it with Eureka Discovery Server using [`eureka-js-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client).

I already have some Java based microservices registered with Eureka and  using it through Zuul API Gateway.

When I try to invoke a specific endpoint on my Node.js micro-service via API Gateway, it throws an error:

```
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not 
have available server for client: tryout
```

Note: `tryout` is the name of my demo service application.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue setting vipAddress same as the app name

> vipAddress: your_app_name

in the eureka client config solved it.